# Where does Skype Desktop 8.x for Windows store its messages, it stopped using main.db

Tags: windows-7, skype, messaging

On my machine, since 24 July 2018, Skype Desktop 8.x for Windows 7 (Skype version 8.29.0.50) does not store its messages anymore in `C:\Users\UserNameHere\AppData\Roaming\Skype\SkypeUserNameHere\main.db` (timestamp is 24 July 2018).

When I export messages (the [instruction is out-of-date](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA392/how-do-i-manage-my-conversation-history-in-skype-for-windows-desktop), but there's still an export function that says "Export chat history from Skype 7.x"), it only exports up until that date to HTML.

- How can I export more recent messages for offline viewing?
- In the absence of such option, what is the new location of the `*.db` SQLite file in Windows 7?

I may be able to get messages from my Windows 10 laptop, where it is well documented, but not all Skype instances are in-sync, hence I prefer to get all history in my backups and for offline viewing / analysis.

*(Note: other threads on this subject only seem to list the UWP location and/or the old Skype 7.x location)*

*(Also note that tools like NirSoft Skype Log Viewer and BitRecover Skype Chat Viewer all use the historical location of Skype 7 and don't find the new messages)*

Comment: I STILL need the answer for precisely where this file is, and how to grab a copy of it in the "new and improved Skype DATABASE FILE".  This "duplicate question" only has this "(non)-answer", "just copy and paste from the web page".  This duplicate question does NOT answer this question.  This OP wants the FILE, while the "duplicate" only wants to "expert" it, which might be close, but not complete enough to implement PROPERLY.
   Maybe there isn't a good answer, or won't be for a while until someone figures it out.

Comment: I need the same answer.  Skype forced me to update in mid Dec 2018, and since then I don't know where chat history is stored, either online or locally on the Win7 machine I use for Skype, but I need to find out and save, before chats are lost after the 6 month limit.  None of the Microsoft forums have an answer on this, and I have found it anywhere else either